# ? Symbol in jdbc clob

Tags: java, jdbc, character-encoding, clob

I have a problem while writing and reading text with « , » characters into an Clob object.
I tried multiple options (using clob.setCharacterStream(0L) etc) but couldn't find a solution.

```
Connection conn = getConnection();
String str = new String("Bank «My Money»".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Clob myClob = conn.createClob();
myClob.setString(1, str);

String res = myClob.getSubString(1, str.length());
System.out.println(res);
```

The result is "Bank ?My Money?"

Comment: Oracle database?   In that case, what version, what the database characterset?  I seem to remember that some functions returned varchar2, ie. using the database character set or the character set of your connection.

Comment: Also, I just read a java string is always UTF-16.  You could try with byte[].

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Java strings internally being UTF-16 has nothing to do with how it is actually encoded to a destination.

Comment: Why are you using `new String("Bank «My Money»".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`? If your default character set isn't also UTF-8, this will replace those guillemets with a ? or mojibake. Using `"Bank «My Money»"` is sufficient to define a string with that value (assuming your code is compiled using UTF-8).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but it makes "Bank «My Money»".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) useless when the result is stored in a String.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille It is not just useless, if the default character set of OPs system is not UTF-8, it could be a potential cause for the observed problem (because you then convert UTF-8 bytes to a string using a different character set). For example, if the default character set is GBK, then this will produce a string `"Bank ?My Money?"`, if it is Cp1252, it will produce `"Bank ?«My Money?»"`, if it is koi8, it will produce `"Bank ?╚My Money?╩"`, etc. On top of that, the database might throw in additional character set conversion issues.